# Creating an IK rig on an armature with disconnected bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I have a skeleton imported as FBX from a video game, and to make modifying animations easier, I want to make an IK rig for it. However, it imports with all bones disconnected from one another.

I know that the IK constraint doesn't properly work on armatures with disconnected bones, but I'm certain there's a solution or a workaround of some kind.

Moving or rotating the original armature's bones around in edit mode is not an option, it destroys existing in-game animations.

Here's the .blend file I'm working with:

[MaleRig.blend](https://puu.sh/Jnu97/1ef4c99e3a.blend)

In the .blend file I have two armatures: One rough IK armature with connected bones, and the original. I was messing around with things to try and see if there was a way to parent the original armature to the IK armature I have. If anyone could help me with that, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing and exporting FBX files, different programs do it differently, in blender you can activate auto-rotation so that all the bones point to each other correctly.

[image]

Also when exporting you can choose where the bones point. But you should first test in your game engine which case works for you before rigging the character. Try to make a simple animation and export it to your game engine to see if you can use the new animations in your game engine.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the existing armature in any way. I was moreso looking for a workaround or a way to append this skeleton to another because of that limitation. I did this before and while I thought it might help, it only deformed the model horribly

Comment: @conicaldog I had an idea of how you could link your rig with IK to your original rig, it's a bit complicated but I leave this [video with the process](https://youtu.be/qQoONVBIuVg). It is actually simple, but convoluted, you must first make a copy of the original rig, join it to the rig with IK and parent each bone of the original rig to its corresponding one in the rig with IK. Then you create a rotation constraint of the copy bone to the original bone. And finally, after animating, you bake the animation where you remove the rotation constraints you created and only the animation remains.

Comment: I can try this out later today, thank you so much for the video and the time you took to help out. Looks promising!

Comment: Went ahead and tried this and it works exactly how I imagined. I had to add some copy location constraints (set to Local with Parent) to every bone too but, convoluted or not, it works. You are a saint.